# curl: (52) Empty reply from server but able to ping the server

Tags: curl

Hi when i execute this command to connect to the server i am getting above message .

```
curl -w"\n" -X POST "host:port/v3/namespaces/default/artifacts/sqljdbc4" \
-H "Artifact-Plugins: [ { 'name': 'sqlserver', 'type': 'jdbc', 'className': 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' } ]" \
-H "Artifact-Version: 2.0" \
-H "Artifact-Extends: system:cdap-etl-batch[3.3.2, 3.3.2]/system:cdap-etl-realtime[3.3.2, 3.3.2]" \
--data-binary @/home/cdap/Downloads/sqljdbc4-2.0.jar
```

..I tried this also `curl -v host:port/status but got the same error ..I tried with the curl -v google.com for that i was getting reply .I was able to connect to the host using jdbc odbc connection using java code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this can be found in the following CDAP Google Groups thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/cdap-user/gsNIlSp2Lok

If you are using Data pipeline make sure that the parent artifact for data pipeline is included as well. Here is a curl call that will enable the JDBC driver to be used with all three pipeline types.

```
curl -w"\n" -X POST "<HOSTNAME>:10000/v3/namespaces/default/artifacts/sqljdbc4" \
-H "Artifact-Plugins: [ { 'name': 'sqlserver', 'type': 'jdbc', 'className': 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' } ]" \
-H "Artifact-Version: 2.0" \
-H "Artifact-Extends: system:cdap-data-pipeline[3.3.2, 3.3.2]/system:cdap-etl-batch[3.3.2, 3.3.2]/system:cdap-etl-realtime[3.3.2, 3.3.2]" \
--data-binary @/home/cdap/Downloads/sqljdbc4-2.0.jar
```